# Wildfly war deployment timeout error :WFLYCTL0348

Tags: jboss, wildfly-13

Getting error - Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability, I have increased the timeout still getting the same error

Comment: What is the size of your WAR?

Comment: @James Its 270 MB

Comment: That's a rather large deployment. Are you by chance including a bunch of the Java EE libraries that could be culled out to reduce the size?

Comment: You may want to check https://community.appian.com/support/w/kb/318/kb-1095-jbas013412-timeout-after-300-seconds-waiting-for-service-container-stability-error-thrown-during-jboss-startup